# Spring Batch process different types in one step

Tags: spring-batch

I have a batch job that reads records from a file. I want to convert said records to PojoA (all strings). I want to run each record throw a validator ensure all fields are present. I then want to transform PojoA to PojoB. The issue I have is that I am unable to change the type of object mid-step.

```
return getStepBuilder("downloadData")
        .<PojoA, PojoA>chunk(1000)
        .reader(pojoAReader())
        .processor(pojoAValidator)
        .writer(pojoAWriter)
        .processor(pojoAToPojoBTransformer) <- issue here, <PojoA, PojoB> 
        .write(pojoBWriter)
        .build();
```

The reason PojoB exists is because PojoA is all strings; I want to persist all records regardless if they're invalid. PojoB has the accurate data types, e.g. Dates, numbers.

I think I need another step that deals with  but how do I pass the PojoA's to step 2?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare two processors/writers like:

```
    .processor(pojoAValidator)
    .writer(pojoAWriter)
    .processor(pojoAToPojoBTransformer) <- issue here, <PojoA, PojoB> 
    .write(pojoBWriter)
```

You need to use a composite processor/writer for that.

Here is a quick example for a composite processor with processor1 (Integer -> Integer) then processor2 (Integer -> String):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<String> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (String item : items) {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor1() {
        return item -> item + 1;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, String> itemProcessor2() {
        return String::valueOf;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, String> compositeItemProcessor() {
        CompositeItemProcessor<Integer, String> compositeItemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        compositeItemProcessor.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(itemProcessor1(), itemProcessor2()));
        return compositeItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Integer, String>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(compositeItemProcessor())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to write the Integer objects to a DB table, validate them, if they pass, convert to String, then write the String objects to a DB table. I am able to do the later, but when I added an Integer writer to the config suggested, it's complaining that my IntegerWriter isn't of the form String, which is correct - it's of type Integer. Is it possible to get around this?

Comment: In my example above, adding in your composite processor, writer(pojoAWriter) won't compile.

Comment: Having thought about it, my use case does go against Batch's RPW paradigm; I'm essentially asking for RWPW. I will have to break this down into 2 steps and pass the data between the 2 steps via a queue-type solution. I'm surprised Batch hasn't come up with a solution to this problem already.